# OpenSSL & python - certificate verify failed - difference in build using source or miniconda

Tags: python, openssl, conda, miniconda

I'm having trouble sending emails with Python, which fail because of:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)
```

Although this does not happen with all OpenSSL libraries:

With some it works and with some it doesn't. When I install OpenSSL using miniconda3, it works (both in version 1.1.1 and 3.0.9). But when I build OpenSSL myself from source it gives the above error (both in version 1.1.1 and 3.1.1).

Note that in all cases `openssl` command works, but when using Python for sending email it fails with the self built OpenSSL library. I built `python` using `pyenv` and depending which library is pointed to by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it fails or succeeds.

How can I build OpenSSL so that it works just like the version installed by miniconda3?

What is the difference between both?